# Sharing Gifs Swift

Tags: ios, swift, gif, uiactivityviewcontroller

How would I share a Gif in Swift? The method I am using right now to share the Gif URL only shares one image and does not share the animated Gif image. Here is what I have right now:

```
        var cell = self.collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(index)
        println(index.item)
        var URLString: String = contentArray[index.item].contentUrlStirng
        var shareURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "\(URLString)")!
        var shareImage: UIImage = UIImage.animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFURL(shareURL)
        let firstActivityItem: Array = [shareImage]
        let activityViewController:UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: firstActivityItem, applicationActivities: nil)
        self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The `URLString` contains a .gif link. Would anyone know how to share the Gif image?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have figured out the answer. You don't have to share the actual image. To share a gif all you do is share the data as such:

```
 var cell = self.collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(index)
        println(index.item)
        var URLString: String = contentArray[index.item].contentUrlStirng
        var shareURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "\(URLString)")!
        var shareData: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: shareURL)!
        let firstActivityItem: Array = [shareData]
        let activityViewController:UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: firstActivityItem, applicationActivities: nil)
        self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: Curious about this post since I'm trying to share an animated gif to Facebook in my app. Are you sharing to Facebook here? I'm assuming you'd need the Facebook API to do this though.

Comment: This works, but won't work on Facebook. On Facebook you need to share the url to the gif for it to display properly.

Answer (score 2):

**For Swift 4.2 to share GIF Image using UIActivityViewController**

```
let objPhoto = self.arrGiphy[indexPath.row]
let shareURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "\(objPhoto.gifImageFixedHeightURL)")!
let shareData: NSData = NSData(contentsOf: shareURL as URL)!
let gifData:  [Any] = [shareData as Any]

let activityViewController:UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: gifData, applicationActivities: nil)
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 done code

```
@IBAction func sharePressed(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let _ = tempImageView.image else {
      return
    }
if pathGif == nil {
     return
}
let shareURL: NSURL = pathGif! as NSURL
let shareData: NSData = NSData(contentsOf: shareURL as URL)!
let gifData:  [Any] = [shareData as Any]

let activityViewController:UIActivityViewController = 
UIActivityViewController(activityItems: gifData, applicationActivities: nil)

activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view

    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [
       UIActivity.ActivityType.postToWeibo,
       UIActivity.ActivityType.print,
       UIActivity.ActivityType.assignToContact,
       UIActivity.ActivityType.saveToCameraRoll,
       UIActivity.ActivityType.addToReadingList,
       UIActivity.ActivityType.postToFlickr,
       UIActivity.ActivityType.postToVimeo,
       UIActivity.ActivityType.postToTencentWeibo
    ]
    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```