# Swift iOS Facebook SDK: How to share an animated GIF?

Tags: ios, swift, animated-gif, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have a document's directory path of a gif I'd like to post to Facebook, but unfortunately when I use this process, it posts a static image instead of it being animated. I know it's animated because I can save the same image to my camera roll and see that it animates. Is there anyway of posting an animated version of this GIF?

```
let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path) // document directory path

let sharePhoto = FBSDKSharePhoto()
sharePhoto.image = image

let content = FBSDKSharePhotoContent()
content.photos = [sharePhoto]

let shareDialog: FBSDKShareDialog = FBSDKShareDialog()
shareDialog.shareContent = content
shareDialog.mode = .native
shareDialog.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not as issue with your image due to `Facebook` natively not support `gif` image directly uploaded on it.

You can share `gif` image link on `Facebook` and it will show there gif image. Like as commonly peoples are using [giphy](https://giphy.com/), [tenor](https://tenor.com/) website and share gif image link from this website. So gif image display via this type of website.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: One interesting thing I found was someone figuring out how to share a gif, but the post is vague. Not really sure where they are sharing to (could be Facebook). They used NSData from a URL to share it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31765148/sharing-gifs-swift